# grafana: last 24 hours - shifted and 2 hours missing

Tags: sql, grafana

I have a grafana chart showing the data of the last 24 hours

[image]

But the data does not fit the time axis. There is missing 2 hours in the beginning of the 24 hour period. And the last value at 21:27:57 is 66.74 but at this time it was 73.50.
The time axis seems to be shifted by 2 hours. The data at time x shows the data of time x-2h.

The timestamp (datetime) in the SQL database is correct.

EDIT:
Changing the timezone doesn't help much. Using UTC (which is wrong for me) the most recent time on the time axis is about 20:40 (wrong)
[image]

Using UTC+2 (which fits my timezone) the most recent time is about 22:40, the correct local time when taking the screenshot.

[image]

The data is not affected and there is still 2 hours missing in the 24 hour period. And still the most recent value in the chart shows the value of 2 hours ago.

Comment: Are you sure you have the previous data on the MySQL? Have you tested with other intervals (Last 2 days, This week so far, Absolute time range, etc)?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. The database contains data of at least 40 days. No matter which interval I choose, there's always 2 hours missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why, but I figured out that there is a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` needed:

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) AS "time",
  humidity
FROM Sensor_BME280_01
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp
```

instead of

```
SELECT
  timestamp AS "time",
  humidity
FROM Sensor_BME280_01
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp
```

The value `timestamp` is of type `DATETIME` in a MariaDB.